# Pagination - How to wait till dataSource is ready/available

Tags: json, angular, typescript, pagination

I have a pagination service and component which is working fine except that the dataSource is empty when loading the page first time. By second time, the dataSource is ready and I can display the dataTable and paginate.

Is there any fix to work around this issue, so that the function is invoked after the data is ready/loaded?

`setTimeOut()` would not be an option based on my tries.

**`list-user.service.ts`**:

```
let registeredUser:USers[] = [];
@Injectable()
export class ListUserService {
    constructor(public loginService:LoginService){}
    getUserDatasource(page:number, limit:number, sortBy?:string, sortType?:DatatableSortType): IPaginableUsers {

      this.loginService.getUsersList().subscribe(
        (res) => {
          registeredUser = res.message
            return registeredUser; 
        }, (err) => {})
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

**list-users.component.ts**:

```
export class ListUsersComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

    ...
    ...
    constructor( private listUserService:ListUserService, private changeDetectorRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
            this.fetchUserDataSource();
    }
       ngOnInit(){}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (this.datatable) {
            Observable.from(this.datatable.selectionChange).takeUntil(this.unmount$).subscribe((e:IDatatableSelectionEvent) =>
                this.currentSelection$.next(e.selectedValues)
            );

            Observable.from(this.datatable.sortChange).takeUntil(this.unmount$).subscribe((e:IDatatableSortEvent) =>
                this.fetchUserDataSource(this.currentPagination.currentPage, this.currentPagination.itemsPerPage, e.sortBy, e.sortType)
            );

            Observable.from(this.pagination.paginationChange).takeUntil(this.unmount$).subscribe((e:IDatatablePaginationEvent) =>
                this.fetchUserDataSource(e.page, e.itemsPerPage)
            );
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.unmount$.next();
        this.unmount$.complete();
    }

    shuffleData() {
        this.users$.next(shuffle(this.users$.getValue()));
        this.currentSelection$.next([]);
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
       private fetchUserDataSource(page:number = this.currentPagination.currentPage, limit:number = this.currentPagination.itemsPerPage, sortBy:string | undefined = this.currentSortBy, sortType:DatatableSortType = this.currentSortType) {
        if (sortBy) {
          this.currentSortBy = sortBy;
          this.currentSortType = sortType;
        }

        const { users, pagination } = this.listUserService.getUserDatasource( page, limit, sortBy, sortType);

        this.users$.next(users);
        this.currentSelection$.next([]);
        this.currentPagination = pagination;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you MUST subscribe in an ngOnInit to this.listUserService.getUserDataSource in your list-user-component

```
export class ListUsersComponent implements OnInit,...
{
   page:number=1;
   limit:number=5;
   sortBy:string='';
   ....
   ngOnInit() {
     this.listUserService.getUserDataSource(page, limit, sortBy, sortType).subscribe((res)=>{
         ....here ...
     }
  }
```

Comment: No, won't/didn't work. I did update my question and add the rest of the code to make it easier to understand the whole concept. Please. check my update

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this.listUserService.getUserDatasource() return an observable, so you must subscribe to this observable